# React component reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, konvajs

I'm trying to create a new component named 'Connection' that will link two 'Location' components together via a 'Line' component.

I don't seem to be able to figure out how to obtain the X/Y coords from the start/finish locations.

It's the referencing of objects that I just can't wrap my head around.

My current code is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Layer, Stage } from 'react-konva';

import Location from './components/Location';
import Connection from './components/Connection';

// CSS
import './css/App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <Stage width={1400} height={700}>
              <Layer>
                  <Location ref='L1' x={0}      y={0} />
                  <Connection ref="L1,L2" start={this.refs.L1} end={this.refs.L2} />
                  <Location ref='L2' x={250}    y={0} />
                  <Location ref='L3' x={500}    y={0} />
              </Layer>
          </Stage>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Sorry if I'm doing this completely wrong! I'm new to React.

### EDIT: Connection

```
import React from 'react';

import { Line } from 'react-konva';

class Connection extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(props.start));
        this.state = {
            color: 'green'
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Line
                points={[
                    100, 50,
                    250, 50
                ]}
                stroke={this.state.color}
                strokeWidth={2}
                lineJoin='round'
                lineCap='round'
                dash={[17, 5]}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default Connection;
```

The `console.log(JSON.stringify(props.start));` line in the constructor is returning undefined.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by: *how to obtain the X/Y coords from the start/finish locations* -- what bit of code will be obtaining the coordinates, and from what 'vantage point' (where is the calling code that will be using the coordinates)?

Comment: @DanEsparza I want to obtain the x and y coordinates, provided through the props to the Location components. This will all be handled within the Connection component, I'm just trying to figure out how to access these variables by passing them through as the `start={...}` is complaining about L1 and L2 not existing.

Comment: Show the code that is trying to access the `props` you describe.  It should probably be in the render code for `Connection`, and it should look something like `this.props.start`

Comment: Since you indicate you're new to React, if you haven't walked through the [thinking in React tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html), you should absolutely do that.  I found it to be tremendously helpful.  Don't skip ahead.  Don't make assumptions based on other frameworks.  For anything other than a very trivial app, use [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) for application data flow.

Comment: @DanEsparza I've updated my question with the connection information. Thanks for the advice, I'll read through that. I've glanced through it but haven't read it all properly.

Answer (score 0):

Do not pass `refs` as properties. On first render `this.refs.L1` is undefined. So child component `Connection` has undefined in this.props.
Instead, you should pass coordinates directly:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    l1Position: { x: 0, y: 0 },
    l2Position: { x: 250, y: 0 },
    l3Position: { x: 550, y: 0 }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Stage width={1400} height={700}>
          <Layer>
            <Location
              ref="L1"
              x={this.state.l1Position.x}
              y={this.state.l1Position.y}
            />
            <Connection
              ref="L1,L2"
              start={this.state.l1Position}
              end={this.state.l2Position}
            />
            <Location
              ref="L2"
              x={this.state.l2Position.x}
              y={this.state.l2Position.y}
            />
            <Location
              ref="L3"
              x={this.state.l3Position.x}
              y={this.state.l3Position.y}
            />
          </Layer>
        </Stage>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```